# Base64 Or UIImage.

Tags: ios, swift, performance

Based on other question, a `based64` image `Data` is about **+37%**  extra size of the actual String.

Therefore consider this case.

An **API**  Client responses with an `Array` of `Object`,

The object contains a lot of properties ..etc, but the one matters is a property i found with a `Key` of `ImageString64` that returns an image of `maxWidth` & `maxHeight`  by `300x300`.

**Desired solution:**

> I want the fastest, yet memory friendly way to `decode` those images

**Notes to consider:**

> I do know how to `encode` them, the question is where and why, does it
>   even matter ?

Options i have:  `//You can add yours if you have better one`

1- inside the `Request` response `callback`

2- pass those `Objects` with their `ImageString64` as they are plain `String`, and then Decode them inside the `UIViewController`.

More general information about the response:

1- maximum array of object as response is limited between 6 - 9 .

2- each response object, has 17 `Keys`.

Comment: Use should consider using Lazy Loading.

It means DON'T load/download resources before it needed. So instead of actual image (in any kind of string, base64, etc.) just pass URL of the image to the app. Then load them as user starts to see it. Take a look at today modern apps likes instagram. The media doesn't download if you don't scroll to its corresponding post.

Comment: mmmm i think i responded to it as answer .. this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with the base64 decoded image, I will transform it neither in the request call back or the view controller.

You should have a type of internal repository, from where your view controllers get the `Object` instances. The repository contains the raw data, with the base64 string.

If you access one of the object instances from the repository, you should transform the base64 string to an `UIImage` instance. The view controller should only see the `UIImage`.

To get good performance for transform and showing the data, you should do this transform before trying to display it, but as mentioned, only if its needed.

If you want to display the data in an `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` you should use the prefetching protocols `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data) or `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching).

What's your use case for displaying the images?